# ¿Cómo extraer el nombre de archivo y la extensión en Bash?

Tags: bash, archivo

Supongamos que tengo una variable `$f` que contiene la ruta de un archivo `/home/juan/hola.txt`. Ahora quiero extraer el nombre del archivo (`hola`) y su extensión (`txt`). ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Se me ocurre utilizar `awk` para extraer el nombre+extensión y la extensión sola:

```
$ awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' <<< "/home/juan/hola.txt"
hola.txt
$ awk -F\. '{print $NF}' <<< "/home/juan/hola.txt"
txt
```

Pero extraer el nombre resulta algo más complicado, por lo que se me ocurre un `sed` algo más farragoso:

```
$ sed -r 's#.*/(.*)\.([^\.]+)#\1#' <<< "/home/juan/hola.txt"
hola
```

Viendo que se complican las expresiones me pregunto: ¿existe alguna manera de realizar estas operaciones utilizando solamente Bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se pueden utilizar las siguientes operaciones con cadenas de Bash:

```
$ archivo="/home/juan/hola.txt"
$ f="${archivo##*/}"             # elimina todo hasta la última /
$ echo "$f"
hola.txt
```

Extensión:

```
$ echo "${f##*.}"    # elimina todo hasta el último punto
txt
```

Nombre del archivo:

```
$ echo "${f%.*}"     # elimina todo desde el último punto
hola
```

---

Alternativamente, se puede usar `basename` para extraer el nombre del archivo de una ruta dada:

```
$ basename "/home/juan/hola.txt"
hola.txt
```

Comment: no funciona para comprobar la extensión de un archivo. cuando un archivo no tiene extensión, este simplemente imprime el nombre.

Comment: @juenDiegoGuzman bueno habría que hacer algún tipo de comprobación de si nombre fichero = extensión.

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto a la solución mencionada en la pregunta usando `awk`, la cual considero es válida para **extraer la extensión del archivo**, me parece pertinente una explicación sobre su funcionamiento.

---

Para determinar la extensión, también puedes usar `awk` con la opción `-F` (field separator):

```
$ echo "archivo.tar.gz" | awk -F . '{print $NF}'
gz
```

Lo que está pasando es que `NF` contiene la cantidad de campos en el input, por lo que está imprimiendo el último que en este caso es `gz`. Lo anterior sería equivalente a:

```
$ echo "archivo.tar.gz" | awk -F . '{print $3}'
gz
```

Y los dos primeros serían:

```
$ echo "archivo.tar.gz" | awk -F . '{print $2}'
tar
$ echo "archivo.tar.gz" | awk -F . '{print $1}'
archivo
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Nótese que la opción de usar `NF` ya la mencioné en la pregunta. En cuanto a usar `$1` y `$2`, no me gustan porque no son generales: dado un archivo, no siempre será fijo.

Comment: Esa respuesta es con awk, no con bash. Yo sé que a menudo awk es disponible, pero la pregunta es por bash, y es posible con bash sólo.

Comment: @Flimzy Te refieres a un script?

Comment: @fedorqui Tienes razón, con respecto a $1 y $2 eran pars explicar el uso de $NF y no especificamente para extraer el nombre

Comment: @CésarBustíos gracias. Sí, la explicación es buena y útil.

Answer (score -2):

Sólo lista el directorio, antes del awk

```
ls files | awk -F . '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Hola Luis y gracias por tu aportación. Lamentablemente, no creo que esto sea demasiado útil. Puede que funcione en algún caso, pero por ejemplo si el nombre contiene algún punto tampoco funcionará. Probablemente después podrías coger todo menos el último campo, pero hacerlo no es trivial.