# extraer de una variable que almacena una ruta, el nombre del archivo.pdf (BASH)

Tags: bash, pdf

dentro de mi variable tengo una ruta que además contiene el nombre del archivo.pdf. Este archivo pdf y su ruta siempre cambian cuando se ejecuta pero la estructura siempre es la misma: $ruta que almacena tanto la ruta como el nombre del archivo.
Tengo esto:

```
echo "arrastra el archivo "
read heavy
ruta=${heavy:1:-1}
```

Hasta ahí bien porque almaceno en $ruta todo el texto limpio sin las comillas, pero no soy capaz de extraer el nombre del archivo.pdf
La pregunta es ¿como corto el texto contenido en la variable $ruta, dejando solo el archivo.pdf ya que cambiarán cada vez que ejecute el programa?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo extraer el nombre de archivo y la extensión en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/663/c%c3%b3mo-extraer-el-nombre-de-archivo-y-la-extensi%c3%b3n-en-bash)

Answer (score 1):

```
    echo "arrastra el archivo que deseas reducir"
    read pdfheavy
    
 

# quito ' del principio y el final resultante de arrastrar el archivo.
rutapdf=${pdfheavy:1:-1}
#elimino toda la ruta hasta el ultimo / para obtener nombre del archivo pdf
capturanombrepdf=${rutapdf##*/} 
#creo la variable que almacena el nombre del archivo con su extensión
nombrepdf=${capturanombrepdf##*/*}
```

Comment: Saludos, intenta siempre agregar una explicación al código que propones (como funciona y si es posible links de documentación), recuerda que hay usuarios que son nuevos en programación y no entenderán tu respuesta, de esta manera tus respuestas ganarán más puntos de reputación. ;)

Comment: Hola @Israel-ICM, toda la razón. Creo que con esto puede servir ;)