# eliminar de la ruta el nombre de archivo contenidos en variable (bash)

Tags: bash, variables

Tengo una ruta contenida en variable que a su vez contiene el nombre del archivo, quiero contener el nombre de la ruta sin el archivo pero no me funciona %% ,os dejo el ejemplo:

```
  echo "arrastra el archivo que deseas reducir"
    read pdfheavy
    
    rutapdf=${pdfheavy:1:-1}
    capturanombrepdf=${rutapdf##*/}
    rutasinarchivo=${$rutapdf%/*} # me da error, % me sale en rojo (uso Vim)

echo $pdfheavy #Devuelve:'/home/usuario/Escritorio/AutoCad_CM.pdf'
echo $rutapdf #Devuelve:/home/usuario/Escritorio/AutoCad_CM.pdf
echo $rutasinarchivo #Devuelve:linea x: ${$rutapdf%/*}: sustitución errónea
```

Entiendo que % elimina todo hasta que encuentra / empezando por el final, no entiendo el error.

Comment: pon por favor un [mcve] para ver qué tienes, qué te da y qué querrías que te diera. Entiendo que esto es continuación de [tu anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/468299/83).

Comment: dale a [edit] para poner los detalles en la publicación, pues en comentarios no se ve bien.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', editado. Sí, es continuación de ese mismo hilo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría dirname:

```
rutasinarchivo=$( dirname $rutapdf )
```

Esas sustituciones fancy no las conozco :-)

Comment: Otro hechizo Harry Potter: un encantamiento que funciona, no se sabe cómo, ni dónde, ni cuando aplicarlo ni contraindicaciones. ¿Qué aprendi con esta respuesta? Nada.

Comment: Que idiota.... es `dirname` (eso lo escribí antes de verificar en mi bash y se me olvidó ajustar.... **y** pueden ver que es lo que sirvió de base a la respuesta que puso Juan Carlos luego de una semana de hecha la pregunta, genios).

Comment: Justo, con dirname, muchas gracias. todo funciona, pero me quedo con la duda de por qué no funciona la línea: rutasinarchivo=${$rutapdf%/*} Teóricamente sirve para sustituir todo hasta la primera / que encuentre empezando por el final...

Comment: Será porque `/` es un caracter especial en este tipo de circunstancias? Trata escapándolo colocando `\/` a ver si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usa `dirname` y `basename` de la siguiente manera:

```
pdfheavy='/home/usuario/Escritorio/AutoCad_CM.pdf'

rutapdf=$(dirname $pdfheavy)
nombrepdf=$(basename $pdfheavy)

echo $rutapdf
echo $nombrepdf
```

El resultado es:

```
/home/usuario/Escritorio
AutoCad_CM.pdf
```